JSON Path Expression Filter Property Filtering on property values in a Single Object
I am using Newtonsoft.Json and the SelectTokens method of the JObject. I am trying to get only the properties that do not have an empty array as it's value. Here is the current code that I am trying and it doesn't seem to working :(
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var item = JObject.Parse(@"
  {
    'date': '2024-12-27',
    'availability': {
      '7:00': [],
      '8:00': [],
      '9:00': [],
      '10:00': [
        {
          'id': 2583
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ");


var availability = item.SelectTokens("$.availability.*[?(length()>0)]").ToList();

Anyone have an idea to only get the property names (using the filter expression) of the availability object that have an array length greater than 0? This currently gives me an exception.
Thanks!

@.length and length() and similar expressions are not supported for JSONPath queries by Json.NET.  See Unable to use JSONPath expressions like @.length #1318.

I believe that JsonPath.Net supports this for queries against JsonNode from System.Text.Json, if you were willing to switch.

You don't need to use SelectTokens(), simply use Properties() after you cast an object as JObject
var availabilityObject = item["availability"] as JObject;
var nonEmptyKeys = availabilityObject.Properties()
    .Where(p => p.Value is JArray array && array.Count > 0)
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .ToList();

Fiddle link CLICK ME

Thanks. I was trying to use JSON Path expressions but I don't think this is actually possible for this query: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm

@KarlGardner Unfortunately yes, It doesn't support advanced filtering.

For specificity, JSON Path doesn't support something property names or indices.  See https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base/issues/516 for any potential support in a follow-up to RFC9535.
